# boost BGL: smallest_last_vertex_ordering asserts false if a graph has no vertices

Tags: c++, boost

For example, the follow code asserts false from bucketsort.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS, // outedgelist
        boost::vecS, // vertexlist
        > Graph;
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor VertexDesc;
Graph graph;
boost::vector_property_map<VertexDesc> order;
boost::smallest_last_vertex_ordering(graph, order);
```

Is this expected?